# Elementary questions on orbits

Tags: group-theory

Suppose a group $G$ acts on a set $X$.  I know what is meant by "an orbit of a point $x\in X$".

1. For $Y\subset X$, what does "$Y$ is an orbit" mean? Does it mean "for some $x\in X$, $Y$ is an orbit of $x$" ?
2. Consider a right action $(P, A) \mapsto {}^tPA\bar P$ of $\mathit{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$.  A textbook at hand says a subset $\{A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})\mid A\ \text{is a positive-definite Hermitian matrix}\}\subset M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is an orbit.  Why is this true?

Edit: Since the word *something* seemed confusing, I replaced it with $Y$.

Comment: An orbit is a set. For instance, the orbit of $1$ under the permutation $(124)$ is $\{1, 2, 4\}$ while the orbit of $3$ is $\{3\}$. So the "something" must be a set.

Comment: You may find [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92510/finding-orbits-of-a-given-permutation/92516#92516) answer of mine, where I discuss a misconstrued definition helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For 1: It would be wrong to say "*an* orbit of a point $x\in X$", since a point has exactly one orbit (under a given action), so it's "*the* orbit of a point $x\in X$" (under the given action). Thus the indefinite article is free to be used in the case where $x$ isn't specified; so yes, "$O$ is an orbit" (under the given action) means "for some $x\in X$, $O$ is the [not an] orbit of $x$" (under the given action).

For 2: Positive-definite Hermitian matrices can be diagonalized. Let $A$ and $B$ be two such matrices, and let $A={^t}SC\bar S$ and $B={^t}TD\bar T$ be their diagonalizations, with ${^t}S\bar S=1$, ${^t}T\bar T=1$ and $C$ and $D$ positive real diagonal matrices. Then $B={^t}PA\bar P$ with $\bar P={^t}SC^{-1/2}D^{1/2}\bar T$. Thus all positive-definite Hermitian matrices are in the same orbit of this action.

Comment: Since my native language (in which the textbook I'm reading is written) lacks articles, I wasn't sure which article should be used.